# Google Charts Tooltips only works with a first row that has no tooltips

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to use tooltips in a google bar chart, and am running into a weird issue where my tooltips only work if the top row of my datatable has no tooltips in it.

When I do this, the chart doesn't render:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Report','Ineffective', 'Developing', 'Effective', 'Highly Effective'],
    ['Growth Rating',{v:18, f:'tooltip text'},{v:12, f:'tooltip text'},{v:66, f:'tooltip text'},{v:4, f:'tooltip text'}],
    ['Composite Rating',{v:6, f:'tooltip text'},{v:12, f:'tooltip text'},{v:58, f:'tooltip text'},{v:25, f:'tooltip text'}]
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
     new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')).
      draw(data,
       {title:"TITLE",
        colors: ['#638FBC','#FFE17C','#FFA87C','#204C7A'],
        hAxis: {title: "Percent of Educators", viewWindow:{max:105, min:0}, titleTextStyle: {italic: false}},
        chartArea: {width: "60%"},
       isStacked: true}
      );
}
```

but if I do this, the chart renders fine

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Report','Ineffective', 'Developing', 'Effective', 'Highly Effective'],
    ['Empty', 0 ,   0 , 0   , 0   ],
    ['Growth Rating',{v:18, f:'tooltip text'},{v:12, f:'tooltip text'},{v:66, f:'tooltip text'},{v:4, f:'tooltip text'}],
    ['Composite Rating',{v:6, f:'tooltip text'},{v:12, f:'tooltip text'},{v:58, f:'tooltip text'},{v:25, f:'tooltip text'}]
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
     new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')).
      draw(data,
       {title:"TITLE",
        colors: ['#638FBC','#FFE17C','#FFA87C','#204C7A'],
        hAxis: {title: "Percent of Educators", viewWindow:{max:105, min:0}, titleTextStyle: {italic: false}},
        chartArea: {width: "60%"},
       isStacked: true}
      );
```

I have no idea why adding that extra row makes it work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the support for {v:,f:} cells in arrayToDataTable is a bit spotty at the moment. We'll publish a fix for this in the next version of the library. In the meantime, you can use the google.visualization.DataTable constructor like so:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Report');
data.addColumn('string', 'Developing');
data.addColumn('string', 'Effective');
data.addColumn('string', 'Highly Effective');
data.addRows([
  ['Growth Rating',{v:18, f:'tooltip text'},{v:12, f:'tooltip text'},{v:66, f:'tooltip text'},{v:4, f:'tooltip text'}],
  ['Composite Rating',{v:6, f:'tooltip text'},{v:12, f:'tooltip text'},{v:58, f:'tooltip text'},{v:25, f:'tooltip text'}]
]);
```